# WiFi disabled on Dell Vostro 5459 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

- Dell Vostro 5459
- BIOS version 1.1.3
- Secure boot is off
- Kernel version: Tried installing latest kernel too. Tried copy file  intel corporation 3160 wireless to `/lib/frameware`

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 3165
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 79
   serial: e0:94:67:b4:d5:a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.11-041511-generic firmware=29.610311.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:129 memory:d5100000-d5101fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: enp3s0
   version: 10
   serial: 20:47:47:75:d2:4d
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:124 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d5004000-d5004fff memory:d5000000-d5003fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: enp0s20f0u3
   serial: 4e:1d:ca:50:7e:8e
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.1.156 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: This question would be much improved if you would be so kind as to [edit] your post to include the output of `rfkill list all` or alternately a [pastie](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) to the output of the wireless info script found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 3):

To bring up a disabled adapter you can use the command:

```
sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up
```

If it tells you, that it is blocked by rfkill you can see if something is blocked with the command

```
rfkill list
```

and unblock it with

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill

Comment: rfkill unblock all

Comment: Find and switch the wireless switch, sometimes called Airplane Mode.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you were to go so far as to [format your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [edit] [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/q/1017912/#comment1651770_1017912) into your answer. Thank you for your effort. Cheers!

Comment: Airplane Mode is disabled too "use hardware switch  to turn off"  message is displayed below Airplane mode,updated to Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: L.S  It is not working  ifconfig: command not found

Comment: during installation there was  intel corporation wireless 3165

Comment: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: My problem was also `Hard blocked: yes` for my Wifi. Running `man rfkill` reveals that `If the device is hard-blocked, e.g. via a hardware switch, it will remain unavailable though it is now soft-unblocked`. After reading this I found a hardware switch for my Wifi that I had never seen on my 12 year old laptop. Seems I had flipped it and not noticed, and I didn't even know it was there!

Comment: This worked for me, once I added the command `sudo dhclient wlp2s0`

Comment: Or with the modern `ip ` command instead: `ip link set wlp2s0 up`

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the above worked for me.
The solution for me was to press the button with the antenna symbol on my laptop.
Usually a button on the top row where the function keys are.

Wifi is enabled by default, perhaps I accidentally hit that button (a dedicated button on my Dell inspiron 7000 without FN combo).